# Adding custom svg icons Angular

Tags: svg, icons

I would like to know how i can add customs svg icons to a mdi.svg file that i have.
The file already have some icons, but i need to put new ones in there.
here is a sample of the mdi.svg

```
<svg><defs><g id="access-point"><path d="M4.93,4.93C3.12,6.74 2,9.24 2,12C2,14.76 3.12,17.26 4.93,19.07L6.34,17.66C4.89,16.22 4,14.22 4,12C4,9.79 4.89,7.78 6.34,6.34L4.93,4.93M19.07,4.93L17.66,6.34C19.11,7.78 20,9.79 20,12C20,14.22 19.11,16.22 17.66,17.66L19.07,19.07C20.88,17.26 22,14.76 22,12C22,9.24 20.88,6.74 19.07,4.93M7.76,7.76C6.67,8.85 6,10.35 6,12C6,13.65 6.67,15.15 7.76,16.24L9.17,14.83C8.45,14.11 8,13.11 8,12C8,10.89 8.45,9.89 9.17,9.17L7.76,7.76M16.24,7.76L14.83,9.17C15.55,9.89 16,10.89 16,12C16,13.11 15.55,14.11 14.83,14.83L16.24,16.24C17.33,15.15 18,13.65 18,12C18,10.35 17.33,8.85 16.24,7.76M12,10A2,2 0 0,0 10,12A2,2 0 0,0 12,14A2,2 0 0,0 14,12A2,2 0 0,0 12,10Z" /></g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
     <defs>
       <g id="access-point">
          <path d="M4.93,4.93C3.12,6.74 2,9.24 2,12C2,14.76 3.12,17.26 4.93,19.07L6.34,17.66C4.89,16.22 4,14.22 4,12C4,9.79 4.89,7.78 6.34,6.34L4.93,4.93M19.07,4.93L17.66,6.34C19.11,7.78 20,9.79 20,12C20,14.22 19.11,16.22 17.66,17.66L19.07,19.07C20.88,17.26 22,14.76 22,12C22,9.24 20.88,6.74 19.07,4.93M7.76,7.76C6.67,8.85 6,10.35 6,12C6,13.65 6.67,15.15 7.76,16.24L9.17,14.83C8.45,14.11 8,13.11 8,12C8,10.89 8.45,9.89 9.17,9.17L7.76,7.76M16.24,7.76L14.83,9.17C15.55,9.89 16,10.89 16,12C16,13.11 15.55,14.11 14.83,14.83L16.24,16.24C17.33,15.15 18,13.65 18,12C18,10.35 17.33,8.85 16.24,7.76M12,10A2,2 0 0,0 10,12A2,2 0 0,0 12,14A2,2 0 0,0 14,12A2,2 0 0,0 12,10Z" />
       </g>
     </defs>

      <use xlink:href="#access-point" x="100" y="100">
      </use>
    </svg>
```

Comment: it seems to work on website, i will try to implement this and give you a feedback. thank you for your time!